# Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, g++, segmentation-fault, gsl

This is probably a silly question, but I can't see what I am doing wrong here. I have the class:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_cdf.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_randist.h>
#include <cmath>
#include "randomnumbergenerator.h"

class RandomNumberGenerator
{
    gsl_rng * rn;
public:
    RandomNumberGenerator();
    ~RandomNumberGenerator();
    double univariate();
    void bivariateGaussian(double rho, double &x, double &y);
};

long currentMicroseconds()
{
    struct timeval now;
    gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
    return now.tv_usec;
}

RandomNumberGenerator::RandomNumberGenerator()
{
    const gsl_rng_type * T;


    gsl_rng_env_setup();

    //T = gsl_rng_default;
    T = gsl_rng_mt19937;
    rn = gsl_rng_alloc (T);
    gsl_rng_set(rn,currentMicroseconds());
}

double RandomNumberGenerator::univariate()
{
    return gsl_rng_uniform(rn);
}

void RandomNumberGenerator::bivariateGaussian(double rho, double &x, double &y)
{
    gsl_ran_bivariate_gaussian (rn, 1.0, 1.0, rho, &x, &y);
}

RandomNumberGenerator::~RandomNumberGenerator()
{
    gsl_rng_free (rn);
}
```

Which I call from here:

```
double x;
double y;
rng.bivariateGaussian(rho, x, y);
```

but I get a segmentation fault on `gsl_ran_bivariate_gaussian (rn, 1.0, 1.0, rho, &x, &y);`

Any idea?

Comment: @Grzenio, Another suggestion is to try compiling with `-O0` to turn of all optimization.

Comment: I think that check your valgrind errors will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check to see if `rn` has really been allocated. It is probably the only thing that can cause segmentation fault.

i tested your code on my computer, it runs okay as far as they can tell. May be check installation of GSL, they have a test suite you can use

Answer (score 1):

Which compiler?  I assume that `rn` is a member variable of RandomNumberGenerator.  Do you initialize it to 0 in the constructor?  You don't seem to be checking for an error return from gsl_rng_alloc, you probably should be because the only thing I can see right off that may be causing a problem is if `rn` isn't pointing to anything valid at the call that's segfaulting.

Looking at the [manual for `gsl_rng_alloc`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Random-number-generator-initialization.html) you can check to see if it returns `NULL` or 0 and then throw an exception if it doesn't.  For example:

```
#include <stdexcept>

RandomNumberGenerator::RandomNumberGenerator()
{
    const gsl_rng_type * T;


    gsl_rng_env_setup();

    //T = gsl_rng_default;
    T = gsl_rng_mt19937;
    rn = gsl_rng_alloc (T);
    if (rn == 0) {
        throw ::std::runtime_error("Failed to allocation a random number generator.");
    }
    gsl_rng_set(rn,currentMicroseconds());
}
```

Also, have you tried compiling with `-O0` to turn of all optimization?

Comment: Pasted the .h file. I am using g++ (one of the latest versions) on Linux. What is the best way to check if rn is allocated (and how to handle if its not)?

Comment: @Grzenio, I'm not seeing the .h file.

Comment: I just merged it just after the #includes

Comment: @Grzenio, I see it.  And I've modified my answer a bit to answer your question and suggest a couple of other possibilities.

Comment: I added your condition, but rn seems to be allocated ok. Only when I first use it in a function other than the constructor it fails. I wonder if the fact that the library I am using (GSL) is C and not C++ has anything to do with this error (because it works fine if I dump all the code to main)

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
double x;
double y;
rng.bivariateGaussian(rho, x, y);
```

are x and y perhaps supposed to be arrays rather than single variables? I'd expect a distribution to produce N values rather than one (or two).

Comment: Sorry for a messy question: rng is the RandomNumberGenerator (defined above). gsl_ran_bivariate_gaussian is defined here: http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/The-Bivariate-Gaussian-Distribution.html

Comment: @Grzenio Yes, but are you expecting a single pair of doubles, or two arrays of doubles (for those of us who don't know what the term 'variate' means - that wasn't the most helpful manual entry I've  seen)

Comment: @Neil Butterworth, the manual entry says it generates a pair of gaussians, so I don't think it wants arrays.

Comment: I am expecting only 2 doubles

Answer (score 0):

I don't program c++, but C. Hopefully this will someway also apply to you. But on C I sometimes use a debugger like GDB or the debugger in Eclipse. I also use [**valgrind**](http://valgrind.org/)(I really like this tool a lot) to fix memory leaks/segmentation faults. I advice you to like at this [tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/valgrind.html)  to get a better understanding of what valgrind can do for you. Valgrind can do a lot more so I would advice you to read about valgrind/helgrind.

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone for your answers. The bug was in the piece of code that I didn't paste :( I was passing an instance of RandomNumberGenerator as a normal parameter. When I changed it to passing as reference it started to work magically.

Comment: It's not magic.  `gsl_rng_free (rn);` frees the gsl structure.  The default copy constructor just makes a copy of the pointer.  It doesn't allocate a new gsl constructor and you haven't defined your own copy constructor.  You should inherit from `::bost::noncopyable` if you have boost, or declare your RandomNumberGenerator to have a private copy constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: Cheers for clarification @Omnifarious, I will do that! Its kind of hard to get your head around C++ after spending a couple of years in C# :)